# How to find if it's the first or second day of the month?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I find if it's the first or second day of the month?

I'm just trying to see if it's the 1st, 2nd or less than the 5th day of the month to do something.

```
If Date = Application.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), 1) Or _
   Date = Application.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), 2) Or _
   Date = Application.WorkDay(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), 3) Then

    MsgBox "1st, 2nd or 3rd day of month"

End If


End Sub
```

Thanking you all in advance

Comment: Use the function day(), it returns just the day of the month

Comment: Do you mean the first or second *work* day?

Comment: *How do I find if it's the first or second day of the month?* Well, `If Day(date)=1 Then msgbox "It's 1st" `

Comment: Thank you all for your kind answers, sticking with simplicity, Foxfire's code looks like what I want, I tried modifying it like so but it's not working ```If Day(Date) = 1 Or 2 Or 3 Then
```

Comment: scratch that, this one worked great ... ```If Day(Date) = 1 Or Day(Date) = 2 Or Day(Date) = 3 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to test if a date (or if unspecified, today) is within the first X **working** days:

```
Function date_is_in_X_days(firstXdays As Integer, Optional dt As Date) As Boolean

    If dt = 0 Then dt = Date

    date_is_in_X_days = False

    With WorksheetFunction
        For t = 1 To firstXdays
            If dt = .WorkDay(.EoMonth(dt, -1), t) Then
                date_is_in_X_days = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Function
```

To test this:

```
Sub test_function()
    If date_is_in_X_days(3) Then MsgBox "1st, 2nd or 3rd day of month"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `DAY` as @Warcupine suggested.

```
Public Function date_is_in_X_days(DayNumber As Long, Optional DateValue As Date) As Boolean

    If DateValue = 0 Then DateValue = Date

    date_is_in_X_days = Day(DateValue) < DayNumber 'Compare the two values which returns TRUE or FALSE

End Function
```

This can then be used as:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Debug.Print date_is_in_X_days(4) 'False if today is >= 4th.
    Debug.Print date_is_in_X_days(2, DateValue("3-Sep-19")) 'False as 3rd is later than 2nd.
    Debug.Print date_is_in_X_days(4, DateValue("3-Sep-19")) 'True as 3rd is earlier than 4th.

End Sub
```

or as a worksheet formula where A1 contains a date:

```
=date_is_in_X_days(5,$A$1)
```